# Layer to follow edge of a scaling layer

Tags: adobe-after-effects

I'm trying to create some templates to use for my videos,
I want to create an animated text composed by 3 words (Left Center Right). The animation will look like that:

```
 Left Right                  Left Center Right   
                ----->       
   Center
```

Basically I have 2 words and then a third one came up, splits the 2 words and puts in the middle of them.

My problem is that I don't know how to get the position of the edges of the center text (the length of the text can change), in such a way that I can use them for spacing left and right form the text in center.

I want to do this in such a way that in Premiere I have only to write the text and not go in AE and change every time the position of words.

Answer (score 0):

Since After Effects CC 2014.2 (aka 13.2), the method [`SourceRectAtTime()`](http://expressions.aenhancers.com/layer-sub.html#layer-sourcerectattime-t-time-includeextents-false) allows to get the bounding box of text and shape layers.

You can thus dynamically relate your `Right` and `Left` animations expressions to the width of the `Center` text.

```
thisComp.layer('Center').sourceRectAtTime().width
```